# How many .where clauses can I use in firestore query in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to use these .where clauses in a firestore query?

```
Stream<List<Trxns>> _streamFromTrxns = _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId)
        .collection('trxns')
        .where('trxnStatus', isNotEqualTo: 'Closed')
        .where('contractDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
        .where('closingDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
        .snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Trxns.fromFirestore(document.data()))
        .toList());
```

I am getting an error because each .where needs to be associated with the same field. How do I implement the filters I have above only in a firestore query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, as expressed.  There's a (scaling) reason Firestore only allows inequality tests on a single field - noting that `!=` is actually an inequality. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

You will need to find another way to structure your data, OR you need to decide if one of the inequalities reduces the number of results enough such you can filter the other  two on the client.  Looking at your example, you might consider a different set of values for `'trxnStatus'` - ```'=='`` is NOT considered an inequality, so it would allow at least *one* of the other inequalities (think some encoding of "not-closed" as a value).

You *can* have more `.where()` queries - but they can't be inequalities unless they are on the same field.